# Could the FAQ links in the legacy off topic close reason be updated?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, off-topic

The new close banners link to the help center. However, the old "off topic" reason links to `/faq` (which now redirects to the help center home page)

> Questions on Physics Stack Exchange are expected to relate to physics within the scope defined in the [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about [closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) here.

Unfortunately, this is confusing (especially for sites other than MSO where the help center has been deployed but the close system hasn't) because:

- The help center is quite large and intimidating. AFAICT it's meant as a reference, not a "read this to understand our scope
- The relevant page -- `/help/on-topic` -- is to the side; it's not the first thing you see, even if you're looking for a "scope definition" (from an outsider's point of view)

Could the link be changed to `/help/on-topic`? Linking them to `/help`  (and not giving much guidance on where to look) is like telling users to RTFM.

See also (mod only): https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9923148#9923148